# Cómo declarar un arreglo tridimensional en java

Tags: java, array

Tengo un problema que no consigo entender y tampoco implementar este tipo de control. ¿Alguien me puede explicar (gráficamente) de manera sencilla el concepto y la forma de implementar un array de 3 dimensiones?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1200621/1983854

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Arreglo unidimensional:

```
[0][1][2]...[n]
```

Arreglo bidimensional:

```
[0/0][0/1][0/2]...[0/n]
[1/0][1/1][1/2]...[1/n]
[2/0][2/1][2/2]...[2/n]
...
```

Arreglo tridimensional (aquí se pone difícil graficamente ;))

```
[0/0/0][0/0/1][0/0/2]...[0/0/n]  [1/0/0][1/0/1][1/0/2]...[1/0/n] ...
[0/1/0][0/1/1][0/1/2]...[0/1/n]  [1/1/0][1/1/1][1/1/2]...[1/1/n]
[0/2/0][0/2/1][0/2/2]...[0/2/n]  [1/2/0][1/2/1][1/2/2]...[1/2/n]
...                              ...
```

En código:

```
int[] arreglo1 = new int[n+1];
int[][] arreglo2 = new int[3][n+1];
int[][][] arreglo3 = new int[2][3][n+1];
```

o en arte ASCII:

```
    /--------------/|
   /              / |
  /              /  |
 /              /   |
+--------------+    /
|              |   /
|              |  /
|              | /
|              |/
+--------------+
```

Para asignar valores directamente en el momento de la declaración, existen dos formas como azúcar sintáctica:

```
int[] arreglo1 = new int[5]{ 1,3,5,7,9 };
```

o

```
int[] arreglo1 = { 1,3,5,7,9 };
// mientras los valores cumplan, se puede omitir la declaración explicita
```

Obviamente aqui tambien se pueden agregar dimensiónes:

```
int[][] arreglo2 = new int[3][5]{ { 1,2,3,4,5 }, { 2,1,3,4,5 }, { 1,3,4,2,5 } };
```

o

```
int[][] arreglo2 = {
                    { 1,2,3,4,5 },
                    { 2,1,3,4,5 },
                    { 1,3,3,2,5 }
                   };
```

o para arreglos tridimensionales

```
int[][][] arreglo3 = new int[2][3][5]{
                                       {
                                         { 1,2,3,4,5 },
                                         { 2,1,3,4,5 },
                                         { 1,4,3,2,5 }
                                       },
                                       {
                                         { 5,4,3,2,1 },
                                         { 3,4,2,5,1 },
                                         { 1,5,4,2,3 }
                                       }
                                     };
```

o

```
int[][][] arreglo3 = { { { 1,2,3,4,5 }, { 2,1,3,4,5 }, { 1,4,3,2,5 } },
                       { { 5,4,3,2,1 }, { 3,4,2,5,1 }, { 1,5,4,2,3 } } };
```

Supongo que se puede deducir como funciona para más dimensiones, cuando me entra tiempo me comprometo de agregar mas bajo la [BEERWARE-LICENSE](https://people.freebsd.org/~phk/).