# ¿Qué hago mal en crear una matriz con numeros pares?

Tags: java

Intento realizar este problema con while y matrices pero no consigo que pinte del 1 al 100 solo con los nº pares.

> PROBLEMA

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int matriz1[][] = new int[5][5];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < matriz1.length) {
        matriz1[i][j]= i*matriz1.length;
        System.out.print(matriz1[i][j]+" ");
        while (j < matriz1[i].length) {
            matriz1[i][j] = j+1; 
            System.out.print(matriz1[i][j]+" ");
        }
        j++;
    }
    i++;
    System.out.println();
}
```

> INTENTO DE RESULTADO AL PROBLEMA

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El incremento usas solamente para compensar el hecho que arreglos empiezan con indice 0. Lo que te falta es una multiplicación por 2 para usar solamente numeros pares.

```
public class Matriz2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // int matriz1[][] = new int[5][5]; // no recomiendo declarar un arreglo así,
        // aun que esta permitido, es menos claro
        // el formato generalmente preferido "Tipo[] var = new Tipo[size];
        int[][] matriz1 = new int[10][5]; // si quieres llegar a 10, necesitas 10 filas
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (i < matriz1.length) {
            //matriz1[i][j]= i*matriz1.length;
            //System.out.print(matriz1[i][j]+" ");
            j =0;
            while (j < matriz1[i].length) {
                matriz1[i][j] = i*10 + (j+1)*2; 
                System.out.print(String.format("%02d ", matriz1[i][j]));
                j++; // tienes que incrementar dentro del loop
            }
            System.out.println();
            i++; // idem
        }
    }

}
```

Resultado:

```
02 04 06 08 10 
12 14 16 18 20 
22 24 26 28 30 
32 34 36 38 40 
42 44 46 48 50 
52 54 56 58 60 
62 64 66 68 70 
72 74 76 78 80 
82 84 86 88 90 
92 94 96 98 100
```

Para ver ejemplos como declarar arreglos, mira [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44612/c%C3%B3mo-declarar-un-arreglo-tridimensional-en-java/44622#44622).

**agregado según comentario**

para impares hay que solamente cambiar el calculo de la segunda dimensión:

```
           matriz1[i][j] = i*10 + j*2 +1;
```

con un ternario, se podría declarar un boolean antes y luego diferenciar en el mismo código:

```
           boolean par;

           matriz1[i][j] = i*10 + (par) ? (j+1)*2 : j*2 +1;
```

Comment: Ya veo lo que hacia mal, como había 2 while`s, pues había nos inicios claros de j igual 0.

Comment: Que pasa si quiero hacerlo solo con números impares, haciendo un if ternario sería la solución mas corta?

Comment: Te lo agregué. Y disculpa si me puse autoritario por la declaración del arreglo, no soy dueño de la verdad. **Si**, se **puede** declarar un arreglo como `int var[] = new int[n]`, pero tengo la experiencia que mucha gente se enredan en código así. Se puede hasta definir un arreglo como `int[] var[] = new int[x][y];`, pero quizás ya te das cuenta que poco consistente eso es con el resto de la estructura en Java.

Answer (score 1):

Viendo que es una secuencia de numeros (2,4,6,8,...100), necesitamos una variable `k` para que se vaya incrementando en cada iteracion en ambos ciclos.

te dejo tu propio codigo, resuelto y comentado.

```
import java.lang.Math; // headers MUST be above the first class

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int matriz1[][] = new int[10][5];//se necesita 10 filas
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k=2;//debe iniciar en 2(ver imagen)
    while (i < matriz1.length) {
        matriz1[i][j]= k;
        k=k+2;//se incrementa en ambos ciclos
        System.out.print(matriz1[i][j]+" ");
        while (j < matriz1[i].length-1) {//j llegara a ser mayor o igual que matriz1[i].length-1, por lo tanto j debe iniciar en 0 nuevamente(ver abajo) 
          matriz1[i][j] = k;
          System.out.print(matriz1[i][j]+" ");
          k=k+2; //se incrementa en ambos ciclos
          j++;
        }

      i++;
      j=0;//se necesita iniciar en por cada iteracion de i 
      System.out.println();
    }

}
}
```

Te recomendaria que uses `for` cuando ya sabes de entrada cuando acabara, en tu caso se sabe de inicio que `i` debe iterar 10 veces y `j`debe iterar 5 veces, y por el contrario, cuando no se sabe cuando acabara se debe usar `while` revisa mi respuesta a este tema, [for vs while - LOOP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45355/for-vs-while-loop/45378#45378)
resolviendo con for:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int matriz1[][] = new int[10][5];

    int k=2;
    for (i=0;i < matriz1.length;i++) {
        matriz1[i][j]= k;
        k=k+2;
        System.out.print(matriz1[i][j]+" ");
        for (j=0;j < matriz1[i].length-1;j++) {
          matriz1[i][j] = k;
          System.out.print(matriz1[i][j]+" ");
          k=k+2;
        }
      System.out.println();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Como sería con do-while's anidados hacer esa matriz de arriba.

Answer (score 0):

Hola te paso una solución para generar matrices de pares con el tamaño de matriz generalizado.

He dividido la funcionalidad en 2 métodos para que quede bien definido que es lo que hace cada parte del código.

```
public class PairMatrixGenerator {

    private static int [][] matrix;

    public static void main(String []args){
        generateMatrix(10,5);
        printMatrix();
    }

    public static void generateMatrix(int rows,int columns){
        matrix = new int[rows][columns];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (i < rows){
            while(j < columns){
                matrix[i][j] = 2 * (i * columns + j + 1);
                j++;
            }
            j=0;
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static void printMatrix(){
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (i < matrix.length){
            while(j < matrix[i].length){
                System.out.printf("%02d ",matrix[i][j]);
                j++;
            }
            System.out.println();
            j=0;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Si quieres meterlo todo en el main sería algo así

```
public class PairMatrixGenerator {

    public static void main(String []args){
        int [][] matrix = new int[10][5];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (i < matrix.length){
            while(j < matrix[i].length){
                matrix[i][j] = 2 * (i * columns + j + 1);
                System.out.printf("%02d ",matrix[i][j]);
                j++;
            }
            System.out.println();
            j=0;
            i++;
        }
    }        
}
```