# ¿Como imprimir un arreglo en Java usando el ciclo for?

Tags: java

Tengo que imprimir una matriz de 4*4 de la siguiente forma

2   4  6  8

10 12 14 16

18 20 22 24

26 28 30 32

Ya intente con esto, pero nada. Lo único con lo que necesito me ayuden es a que la primer variable, j, llegue a 4, con eso creo que me serviría. Disculpen soy nuevo
.

```
public class HolaMundo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         int[][][][] Arreglo = new int[4][4][4][4];

         for(int j =1, k = 0, l = 0, m = 0; j < 4;j++, k++, l++) {
         Arreglo[j][j][j][j]=j *2;
         Arreglo[j][j][j][j]=j *2;
         System.out.println(Arreglo[j][j][j][j]);
         System.out.println(Arreglo[k][k][k][k]);
         System.out.println(Arreglo[l][l][l][l]);
         System.out.println(Arreglo[m][m][m][m]);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

¡Ey que tal amigo!

Para poder recorrer una matriz necesitas dos ciclos, uno que recorra las filas y otro que recorra las columnas.

```
   C1 C2 C3 C4
F1 1 2 3 4
F2 5 6 7 8
F3 9 10 11 12
F4 13 14 15 16
```

Un ciclo estará moviendose dentro de todos los F y dentro de este ciclo se tendrá otro que recorra todas las C (columnas), Cuando acabe de recorrer todas las C pasa al siguiente F y recorre todas las C de esta.
Código:

```
int[][] r = new int[4][4];
        int cont = 1;
        // Recorre las filas
        for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++){
            // Recorre las columnas
            for (int j = 0; j < r.length; j++) {
                // Le agrega un valor a la posición [i][j]
                r[i][j] = cont;
                // imprime el valor agregado
                System.out.print(" " +r[i][j]);
                cont++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Resultado:

```
 1 2 3 4
 5 6 7 8
 9 10 11 12
 13 14 15 16
```

¡Espero te sirva, saludos!

Te aconsejo que leas sobre arreglos multidimensionales, sobre matrices también.

Answer (score 0):

```
package pruebas;

/**
 *
 * @author Moisés Alcocer
 * @web: https://www.ironwoods.es
 */
public class matriz {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        int n = 2;
        int interval = n;

        int size = 4;

        for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
            for( int j = 0; j < size; j++ ) {

                System.out.print( n + " " );

                n += interval;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

} //class
```

La variable **n** contiene la cifra que se va a ir incrementando e imprimiendo.

La variable **interval**, el incremento sobre **n**.

La variable **size** contiene el "tamaño" de la matriz.

Cambiando estas tres variables puedes modificar fácilmente tu matriz, las dos primeras para las cifras a mostrar, y la última para su tamaño. Si por ejemplo ahora necesitas una matriz de 8*8: cambias el valor de **size** a 8. Si quieres que la cifra de inicio y el intervalo sea de 7, cambias el valor de **n** a este número. La idea es que el código permita variaciones de uso con mínimas o ninguna modificación.

Los dos bucles son el primero para recorrer el espacio vertical, de ahí que se imprima un salto de línea al final, el bucle anidado recorre el espacio horizontalmente.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

## Aclaraciones

Cual es la necesidad de utilizar un arreglo de 4 dimensiones. Ya de por si es complicado manejar uno de 2 y manejar uno de 3 es un quebradero de cabeza. No me imagino lo complicado que seria trabajar con uno de 4.

Por lo que veo, lo que quieres lograr lo puedes hacer con un arreglo de 2 dimensiones. Ten en cuenta que las dimensiones en un arreglo no significan el numero de filas que estos pueden tener, si no el numero de direcciones que estos utilizan para almacenar los datos.

El numero de dimensiones de un array se define en el numero de corchetes que a este se le asigne. un array de una dimensión solo posee un corchete `[]`, uno de dos posee dos corchetes `[][]`, uno de tres tres y uno de cuatro... Bueno, ya seria una locura trabajar con un array de tantas dimensiones. Solo ten en cuenta que mientra mas corchetes mas dimensiones.

#### Array de una dimensión

```
int[] array = new int[3];  
123
```

Este array almacena la información en una sola dirección. Que puede visualizarse gráficamente en una columna o una fila.

#### Array de dos dimensiones (bidimensional)

```
int[] array = new int[3][3];
        c
        o
        l
        u
        m
        n
        a
        s
        ⬇
filas➡ 123
        123
        123
```

Este array almacena la información en dos direcciones. Que puede visualizarse gráficamente como una **tabla de Excel**, que posee filas y columnas. El numero de filas se declara en el primer corchete y el numero de columnas en el segundo `[filas][columnas]`. Esto es justo lo que necesitas.

Un **array de 3 dimensiones** seria mas complejo y tendría 3 corchetes`[][][]`, no entrare a explicar como funciona, ya que con uno de dos dimensiones puedes lograr lo que quieres. Pero si te pica la curiosidad, te dejo este enlace:

[Cómo declarar un arreglo tridimensional en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44612/c%C3%B3mo-declarar-un-arreglo-tridimensional-en-java)

## Solucion

Para lograr lo que quieres tienes que declarar un array bidimensional de cuatro filas y cuatro columnas.

```
int[][] arreglo = new int[4][4];
```

> Los nombres de las variables siempre debe empezar con minúscula.

Para recorrer un array de dos dimensiones necesitas utilizar dos ciclos, uno que recorra las filas y otro que recorra las columnas.

```
// Recorre las filas
for (int filas = 0; filas < arreglo.length; filas++) { 

    // Recorre las columnas
    for (int columnas = 0; columnas < arreglo[filas].length; columnas++) {
        arreglo[filas][columnas] = (fila+1) * 2;
        System.out.print(arreglo[filas][columnas]);
    }

    // Cada vez que termina de recorrer una fila, das un salto de linea
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

De esa manera el array se imprimirá como quieres:

```
2  4  6  8

10 12 14 16

18 20 22 24

26 28 30 32
```